# To satisfy x out of y constraints

Tags: drools, drools-planner

I am making a timetabling program which does **one to one** matches from `SubjectTeacherPeriod` (planning entity) to `Period`. There comes a case when I need to: *"for y periods, atleast x of the `SubjectTeacherPeriod` must match a `match_condition`"*

For example, I want to constrain 3 particular periods, atleast two of them to be taught by teachers who match to `asst prof`.

Here is the data structure holding such a constraint:

```
Class XOfYPeriods
  SomeType match_condition 
  int x
  List<Period> Periods //problem
```

`SubjectTeacherPeriod` has a `Period`, of course

```
class SubjectTeacherPeriod
  int id
  SomeType attrib
  Period period
```

---

How do I write a rule that evaluates individual `Period`s from a **list** to check if x number of `SubjectTeacherPeriod`s that are allocated those `Period`s meet the match condition?

Do correct me if I am defining my classes in bad form.

For the sake of example, here is a statement to be evaluated to determine a match: `eval(matches($stp_attrib,$match_condition))`

---

Sorry for the use of Pseudocode if it confused more than clarified. The `SomeType` is actually List< String> and thus the match condition is checked with a `Collections.disjoint`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give it a try, but not sure I completely understand your problem statement:

```
rule "X of Y Periods"
when
    $c : XOfYPeriods( )
    $list : List( size > $c.x ) from
        accumulate( $stp : SubjectTeacherPeriod( matches(attrib, $c.match_condition),
                                                 period memberOf $c.periods ),
                    collectList( $stp ) )
then
    // $list of STP that match the condition and 
    // whose period matches one of the periods in the list
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, a use of `accumulate` and `memberOf` was what I needed.